# Variable Importance with fable::NNETAR?

Tags: r, fable-r

Is there a way to get a view of variable importance from a `fable::NNETAR` model?  Something like the little made-up `nnet` example below?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(NeuralNetTools)
library(nnet)

ts <- tibble(index = 1:1000) %>%
  mutate(
    y = seq(0.5, 1000 / 2, by = 0.5) + arima.sim(model = list(
      ar = c(0.2, 0.3),
      ma = 0.2,
      order = c(2, 1, 1)
    ), 999) %>% as.double(),
    x1 = seq(0.5, 1000 / 2, by = 0.5),
    x2 = 1:1000,
    x3 = 1
  ) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = index)

# Possible to extract variable importance from fable::NNETAR ...
mod <- ts %>%
  model(NNet = NNETAR(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3))
#> Warning: Constant xreg column, setting `scale_inputs=FALSE`

# ... as per the nnet / garson example?
nnet(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = ts, size = 1) %>% 
  garson() +
  ggtitle("NN Variable Importance")
#> # weights:  6
#> initial  value 53799287.386267 
#> final  value 53627119.744357 
#> converged
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Is `fable` installed from `github` ?

Comment: @akrun, yes it is (v0.1.0)

Comment: Variable importance from NNAR is not yet supported by fable. You're welcome to submit a feature request on the Github repository.